# AWS SES (Console) - Can't see sending statistics for more than 24 hours ago

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

In my [AWS SES](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/Welcome.html) console I can only see the [sending statistics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitor-sending-activity.html) for the
**last 24 hours** but no more.

Is there a way to see sending statistics for the last week, month, all time?

[image]

Comment: Absolutely no reason for a down vote here. Perfectly legitimate question that is on topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon SES dashboard only offers last 24 hours activity. If you need to have more, you can setup sns notifications and store them in a DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can track the mail events with event publishing. Here is a post explaining how to: https://mailintel.io/resources/tracking-deliveries-opens-and-clicks-for-amazon-ses. If you don't want to build anything yourself, you can use mailintel.io. Gives you a detailed reporting dashboard.